# Markdown rendering differs when invoked on members of foreach or via a where filter

Tags: jekyll

I wonder if anyone can illuminate this puzzle. I am using a new installation of vanilla jekyll on a Mac. Everything seems to work fine, but I discovered that some text being shown in my page footer was rendering differently on posts and all other pages. On most pages the text would render as HTML, but in posts it was rendering as Markdown. I found a workaround, but it left me with even more questions.

**Context**

I have defined `footer_sections` as a collection to hold portions of the footer. In my `_config.yml` this looks like:

```
collections:
  footer_sections:
    output: false
```

A footer section is then defined in a Markdown file such as `_footer_sections/address.md` as:

```
---
title: Address
order: 1
---
**My Name**  
123 My Street  
My Town, ST 12345  
123-555-5555
```

In my `default.html` I had a footer section in my HTML something like this:

```
<div id="footer">
    {{ site.footer_sections | where: "title", "Address" }}
</div>
```

And my posts are set up like this example:

```
---
title: Silly new post
date: 2017-02-27T12:33:53+00:00
author: Eric Celeste
layout: post
---
Silly post.
```

And finally, the post layout is connected to the default layout like this:

```
---
layout: default
---
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
<p class="meta">{{ page.date | date_to_string }}</p>
<div class="post">
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

**The Problem**

Notice that the `address.md` file is defined in Markdown and then its content is shown in the footer by the inclusion of the section in `default.html`. On all regular pages this would render as HTML (a bold name, a plain address), but on posts like the silly post above, it would render as Markdown (a name surrounded by stars and an address without like breaks).

I thought maybe it had to do with different procedural steps between posts and pages, maybe the Markdown rendering is happening "later" on pages but has already happened "earlier" in posts. I am only two days old on Jekyll, so I really don't know how it works.

In order to test that theory, I tried forcing the Markdown rendering with the `markdownify` filter. I changed the liquid tags in `default.html` so that they read:

```
{% assign section = site.footer_sections | where: "title", "Address" %}
{{ section.content | markdownify }}
```

Oddly, this produced a worse result everywhere. Now no text of any sort appeared in the footer of regular or post pages.

On the theory that maybe the `where` filter is actually different from looping through members of an array with `foreach` I tried another approach:

```
{% for section in site.footer_sections %}
    {% if section.title == "Address" %}
        {{ section.content | markdownify }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That worked! Now the content of the footer sections rendered as HTML on both regular pages and posts.

**My Questions**

Why didn't the initial approach work? What is the difference between rendering of posts and other pages in Jekyll?

While I found workaround, I don't understand why it works. In what ways does pulling out an item from an array with a `where` filter differ from using a member from a `foreach` loop? How does this affect the results of the `markdownify` filter?

Is there a cleaner, simpler way to grab the HTML-rendered content from my sections than looping through them each time I want to use one of them?

Thanks for any insights you may have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

site.footer_sections is an [array](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/types/#array) and the output of the 'where' filter is still an array (but only containing the values that match your condition).

In your case, you are getting a single-element array but it's still an array object.

To see this for yourself use the inspect filter:

```
{% assign section = site.footer_sections | where: "title", "Address" %}
{{ section.content | inspect }}
```

On the other hand, when you loop through the elements with a for loop, at each iteration you get the individual elements of the array. Try using `inspect` inside your loop to see how the two types of your `section` variable differ.

For the 'where' method to work you need to get the actual element from the array either with `first` or `[0]`:

```
{% assign section = site.footer_sections | where: "title", "Address" %}
{{ section.first.content | markdownify }}
```

OR

```
{% assign section = site.footer_sections | where: "title", "Address" %}
{{ section[0].content | markdownify }}
```

**links:**

[array documentation](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/types/#array)

[first documentation](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/first/)

[where documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/)